# Can my Windows 10 PC use iris scanning

Tags: windows-10, biometrics, windows-hello

I think that biometric authentication is *so cool.* I also think that it's the future. I read today that iris scanning (which I think is the coolest branch) can be done by regular RGB webcams. So, my question is, does Windows Hello on my PC support iris scanning? And how can I set it up if it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to:

Start menu > Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options

Under the Windows Hello title, it will state whether or not it is supported.